# Connection error while creating index in elastic search through Lambda function in AWS Lex using Python

Tags: aws-lambda

While creating index in elastic search through Lambda function in **AWS** we are shown following error:

> 'Max retries exceeded with url: //EndpointURL:443/metadata-store
>   (Caused by
>   NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection:
>   [Errno -2] Name or service not known',))'

.

Please help.

Comment: Hii. Welcome to SO. Please make the question easy to be read for people.

Comment: Good thing he said "Please help" or no one would help!